# Nav2 Behavior Tree: cancelControl BTnode doesnt preempt/stop controller

Tags: navigation, ros-humble, nav2

I'm looking to have a behavior tree in ROS2 humble that:

1. Works with the `navigateThroughPoses` navigator plugin of `bt_navigator`.
2. Pauses the navigation operation (the robot must not receive velocity commands) upon receiving a message on a topic.
3. Resumes the navigation operation (the robot must navigate to the pose it was headed to before the operation was paused) upon receiving a message on a topic.

I've come up with a small test solution for this: 
I made a few changes to the default [navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/humble/nav2_bt_navigator/behavior_trees/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml) tree that comes with the `NavigateThroughPoses` navigator plugin.

- A fallback node is added to the root of the tree, along with the first child of this fallback node being a Condition Node to check `/battery_status`.
- The logic being: If the battery is charging pause the navigation,if not resume/continue with it. Note that this is just to test the whole "topic-based control of a BT" concept and is not necessarily a proper usage of the `isBatteryCharging` Node.
- I've also added a `cancelControl` node in sequence with the `isBatteryCharging` node to preempt any on-going navigation.
- the second child of the fallback node is the unchanged `navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery` tree, as seen in the image.
  [image]

Now this BT malfunctions in two ways:

1. when attempting to pause the navigation **after** the robot is given a goal. The `/follow_path`action doesn't seem to be preempted as the controller output in console shows new paths being received: `Passing new path to controller`.
2. When the pausing the navigation **before** giving a goal the robot remains stationary and console output from bt_navigator shows `goal  succeeded`.

Pausing/Resuming involved sending batteryState messages at a fixed rate of 5Hz.

Any suggestions on why this is malfunctioning or any alternate ways of writing this tree?

here is my xml:

```
<root main_tree_to_execute="MainTree">
  <BehaviorTree ID="MainTree">
  <Fallback>
    <Sequence>
    <Condition ID="IsBatteryCharging" battery_topic="/battery_status"/>
    <ForceSuccess>
        <Action ID="CancelControl" server_name="/follow_path" server_timeout="2"/>
    </ForceSuccess>
    </Sequence>
    <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="6" name="NavigateRecovery">
      <PipelineSequence name="NavigateWithReplanning">
        <RateController hz="0.333">
          <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="1" name="ComputePathThroughPoses">
            <ReactiveSequence>
              <RemovePassedGoals input_goals="{goals}" output_goals="{goals}" radius="0.7"/>
              <ComputePathThroughPoses goals="{goals}" path="{path}" planner_id="GridBased"/>
            </ReactiveSequence>
            <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearGlobalCostmap-Context" service_name="global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap"/>
          </RecoveryNode>
        </RateController>
        <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="1" name="FollowPath">
          <FollowPath path="{path}" controller_id="FollowPath"/>
          <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearLocalCostmap-Context" service_name="local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap"/>
        </RecoveryNode>
      </PipelineSequence>
      <ReactiveFallback name="RecoveryFallback">
        <GoalUpdated/>
        <RoundRobin name="RecoveryActions">
          <Sequence name="ClearingActions">
            <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearLocalCostmap-Subtree" service_name="local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap"/>
            <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearGlobalCostmap-Subtree" service_name="global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap"/>
          </Sequence>
          <Spin spin_dist="1.57"/>
          <Wait wait_duration="5"/>
          <BackUp backup_dist="0.30" backup_speed="0.05"/>
        </RoundRobin>
      </ReactiveFallback>
    </RecoveryNode>
    </Fallback>
  </BehaviorTree>
</root>
```

Comment: I don't understand "pause" where is there a "pause" here? I don't understand your (1) malfunction. Your (2) 'malfunction' is pretty clear looking at your tree. If you go through the tree's state, you'll see it returns success because its completed what it aimed to do. If you want it to not succeed, you'll need to modify the tree further based on some condition that you want to also be true.